# Creating a static library with Cocoapod Dependencies

Tags: xcode, static-libraries, cocoapods

I'm trying to create a static library in Xcode. My library consists of a single class. It depends on another library (`RXCollections`).

My tests also depend on other libraries: `OCMock`, and `Foundry`.

For my static library project, I created a podfile for my static library project as such:

```
platform :ios, "7.1"

pod "RXCollections", '~> 1.0'

target :LibraryTests, :exclusive => true do
  pod "OCMock", '3.1.1'
  pod "Foundry"
end
```

Everything builds successfully, but when I run my tests, I get a runtime exception when I try to use `RXCollections` methods: `-[__NSCFSet rx_mapWithBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feaf414c410`.

What's going wrong here?

**UPDATE**

Well, that didn't take long ;) Turns out, CocoaPods was automatically adding `LibPods.a` to my target's "Link Binary with Libraries" build phase, but for some reason, I had to remove that and add the `LibRXCollections.a` specifically. Still not sure why. Any ideas?